# Can't align text to the right in the layout

Tags: android, layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="nope"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_arrive"
            android:onClick="selectNotGoing"
             />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attendingEventInListviewRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:text="eventsName"
            android:height="30sp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:tag="eventsName"
            />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="eventDayOfTheWeek"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/eventDayOfTheWeekTxt"
            android:gravity="right"

            />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="eventTime"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/eventTimeTxt"
        android:gravity="right"
        />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried to google the problem and implement solutions I have found in here. Nothing helped. The code above is my current XML. I need `eventName`, `eventDayOfTheWeek` and `eventTime` to stay in the right side.

I have also tried to clean the project and rebuild it, but it stays the same.

(In the preview the text is in the right side, after the launch it goes to the left)

Before launch(In the preview): http://prntscr.com/db0ekp 
After launch: http://prntscr.com/db0f7t

(The layout is a row inside a list view)

Comment: The text is right-aligned in the TextViews if I run it. Can you specify what's happening in your case?

Comment: I also see the text in the right side while previewing, but when I launch the app it goes to the left.

Comment: Try to add different background colours to the TextViews (e.g. `android:background="#FF0000"`) to see a little better what's happening, and then probably post a screenshot in the question.

Comment: I have edited the question and added relevant screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preview shows your layout without info where it will be inflated, assumes as "wholescreen" layout. but your XML code is piece inside container (`ListView`), which may have set `layout_width` to `wrap_content` (or fixed value). your `ListView` should have `match_parent` (and maybe its parent too). show more code, especially for `Activity` or `Fragment` if you are using.

Comment: I have changed the layout width of the list view from wrap_content to match parent and it worked. Thanks.